# Creation of Data source and JNDI, communication in spring MVC application using annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, datasource, jndi

I am creating a demo application using Spring mvc 3.0.Now i wants to connect the my application to the data base using "JNDI" and annotations. I am searching on the web,but 
not find any good example.

Hopefully somebody could give me a good link where I could learn step by step for the annotation driven spring mvc application that communicate with the db layer with the help of annotation and JNDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is

```
<jee:jndi-lookup/>
```

check this link http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-jee-jndi-lookup for info on using JNDI lookup . Remaining configurations are similar to app without JNDI .

Check a sample [here](http://www.gridshore.nl/blog/index.php?/archives/71-Loading-properties-using-JNDI-within-the-springframework-deployed-on-tomcat.html)